# replace old database in assets with updated version

Tags: java, android, sqlite, assets

I have an app that uses a database (SQLite) in the assets folder which is copied into the data/data...folder on the android device.  The problem is that the data inside the database is a train schedule that is updated every two months.  To further complicate the matter, the data is online in five csv files that are zipped.  I have written a java script that downloads, unzips, parses the data I need, builds the database, and populates it.

Is there a way to update (replace) the database in the assets folder?  At that point a simple delete of the android app database will fire off a copy of the new data.

The real questions:

1. Can I post an updated database that will replace the one in assets?
2. Can I run the java script?
3. Do I need to just write the whole thing in a background running a new thread in the android app?
4. Would it be better to just manually install the database and post the upgrade in a new APK?

Ideas?

Comment: "Is there a way to update (replace) the database in the assets folder?" -- no, other than by shipping a new version of your app that has the updated database in `assets/`. Moreover, that should not be necessary, as once the app is installed and run for the first time, you are copying the database from assets to internal storage, and so it is the copy on internal storage that you are using and would need to be replaced.

Comment: @CommonWare..Thank you, Wasn't sure if I could just do a delete of old and replace new in assets.  I understand it is the internal storage version that it uses.  I have a method in my database helper that would delete and rebuild the internal copy.

Comment: It sounds like you want to provide a service for your app where it can download the latest train schedules every so much time.

Comment: @Rob Meeuwisse..yes but it comes in as zipped csv and needs to be converted to database.  I have the code to do the conversion just wondering the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'm just going to write out my thoughts in an answer instead of the comments.

Like CommonsWare said, you cannot update files in the assets/ dir. They are part of the APK, i.e., they are compiled into your app so you can replace the entire app or nothing at all.

You have a javascript to convert zipped csv files with the train schedule information files to a database that your app can use. I'm assuming that it is this database file that you put in assets/ and then build your app.

Since your app needs to refresh its data every so often it seems the most obvious to me to let your app download it. The thing that is downloaded should be the ready-to-use database, not the set of zipped csv files.

You can convert the zipped csv files into a database on your developement pc and then put that database file in the location where your app can download it.

A service for your app can be very simple. It just has to be a static file server, it does not need to be an API backend. If you rent a server then Nginx, Apache or IIS can do that out of the box for you. You can even do it without renting a server if you put the database file on Github or Dropbox.

When your app starts up, it checks if there's a newer version of the database file than what it currently has, and if so it downloads it. When completely downloaded it can run the same code that you have now for copying from assets/ to data/data but it does the copying from wherever it was downloaded to.

Comment: @Rob..Thank you.  That was the information I was needing.  I can will for now just use my gitHub to at least get it up and functioning for me.  Sorry if the question is a little rudimentary but I've only be doing Java for about 6 months and android for 6 weeks.